# Crossrider Extensions - are they safe

Tags: crossrider

I have started writing an extension using Crossrider, and really like it. But I have read some negative stuff about them being a browser hijacker - in particular search.crossrider.com

I am unsure if search.crossrider.com is a malicious extension built using Crossrider, or Crossrider itself. Among other places, this is a link which recommends you delete this.
http://forums.anvisoft.com/viewtopic-45-1190-0.html

Before I continue developing in this, I thought I would ask the experts.

Any comments, gratefully received.

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Crossrider is very safe to use!

We had some incidents in the past where developers had tried to write malicious extensions using our framework, but with our security co-operations with Google and Facebook we managed to mitigate them. (and the fact that we are a cloud-based solution allows us to remotely disable any malicious use that is against our T&C.)

Besides being very safe Crossrider is also a free and a must-have tool for any extension developers. (There are more than 20,000 developers the Crossrider community)

Crossrider not only provides the technical solution of building the API to support all major browsers including Chrome, Firefox, Internet Explorer and Safari, but also gives the developer further tools and features to solve and simplify all the heavy lifting tasks when it comes to developing and publishing browser extensions:

1. Full statistical dashboards with information on numbers of Installations, Active Users, Uninstalls which can be broken down to per-country and per-browser usage.
2. Crossrider provides an online IDE that developers can actually start coding  extension online in matters of seconds. The developer doesn't need to download any development packages to their computer (unless they really want to), and as you develop, you see your code changes take affect in real-time on your browser.
3. Another feature is Crossrider's auto code update mechanism, where any code change (including new releases or bug fixes) is getting published to all existing users (and new obviously) in matter of hours. Regardless if you have several users or millions.
4. Crossrider also provides advances publishing tools such as embeddable installation widget for your website, direct download links and more.
5. One of those publishing tools is the Advanced Window Installer that can install your extension on all browsers automatically. This installer can be easily configured to the developers needs and we even supply with an automated Code Signing Service where developers can sign their installers in real-time.
6. 24/7 Support - We are really keen about our support. We always strive to keep our response time to the minimum and we treat the smaller developer(s) as it was our most important client. We even try to help developers when it's not 100% Crossrider related questions as we also believe in good karma :)

Hope this helps your decision of working with Crossrider.

p.s Not sure 100% about the search.crossrider.com thread you have mentioned but as we do not have any affiliation with this subdomain (in fact, it does not even exists on our DNS records) you can rest assure this has nothing to do with Crossrider as a framework.

(Disclosure: I work for Crossrider)

Comment: Hi i'm currently using crossrider for one of the extension and its stopped working. i have it in chrome store. it doesn't executes any code anymore is there anything can be changed in package which can make this work?